# Convert ASCII box drawing into Unicode

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, parsing, conversion, unicode

I am shamelessly posting a request for something I would actually find useful.  The task is to take an arbitrary ascii box drawing like this

```
     |
+----+----+
| state A +---+
+---------+   |
              |
         +----v----+
         | state B |
         +---------+
```

... and turn it into something more beautiful using unicode box drawing characters, e.g.

```
     │
╭────┴────╮
│ state A ├───╮
╰─────────╯   │
              │
         ╭────v────╮
         │ state B │
         ╰─────────╯
```

In more detail:

- convert only + - | characters - other characters should be unchanged
- use

  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL (U+2502) │
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL (U+2500) ─
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT ARC DOWN AND RIGHT (U+256D) ╭
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT ARC DOWN AND LEFT (U+256E) ╮
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT ARC UP AND LEFT (U+256F) ╯
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT ARC UP AND RIGHT (U+2570) ╰
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND LEFT (U+2524) ┤
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND RIGHT (U+251C) ├
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND HORIZONTAL (U+252C) ┬
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND HORIZONTAL (U+2534) ┴
  - BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND HORIZONTAL (U+253C) ┼
  - - always replaced with U+2500
  - | always replaced with U+2502
  - + is replaced with a unicode character that depends on the 4 characters north, south, east and west of it (if they exist)
  - < and > are treated as vertical wall segments if north or south of a + (so that you can have arrows terminating in vertical walls of a box)
  - v and ^ are treated as horizontal wall segments if east or west of a + (so that you can have arrows terminating in horizontal walls of a box)
  - + is treated as a wall segment if either north, south, east or west of a + (so that lines can connect next to a box corner)

Testcases

```
+-+     +---+   +---+   |
| +--   |ABC|  -+   |  +++
+-+     ++--+   +---+  +-+
         |
         +--->
  |           +--+
+-v+   +---+  |  |  +-----+
|Hi|  ->   |  +^-+  |world<-----+
+--+   +---+   |    +-----+     |
               |                +--
   |
---+---
   |
```

Becomes

```
╭─╮     ╭───╮   ╭───╮   │
│ ├──   │ABC│  ─┤   │  ╭┴╮
╰─╯     ╰┬──╯   ╰───╯  ╰─╯
         │
         ╰───>
  │           ╭──╮
╭─v╮   ╭───╮  │  │  ╭─────╮
│Hi│  ─>   │  ╰^─╯  │world<─────╮
╰──╯   ╰───╯   │    ╰─────╯     │
               │                ╰──
   │
───┼───
   │
```

Shortest code wins!

Comment: Where is the "intersection", i.e. if the `+` has lines around it everywhere?

Comment: You probably mean _Unicode_ rather than _UTF-8_

Comment: Could we have some test cases? Particularly for edge cases like where two boxes touch at an edge or corner (or clarification that this will never happen).

Comment: @LeakyNun I don't think the intersection should ever be needed.  Box walls always terminate lines (which will end in one of +,<,>,^,v if they hit a box wall, otherwise they end in |,-).  Lines don't enter boxes.  Lines don't cross.

Comment: Would be nice to post the required outputs for those test cases.

Comment: Will boxes ever touch at an edge, e.g. could there ever be pluses in a 'T' shape all touching? Also, there are no test cases that have boxes with a height > 3 or with any other arrow directions.

Comment: Can the output have additional spaces at the end of each line?

Comment: Ugh, I was just composing an answer :-(

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone.  This is my first golfing expedition so I'm just getting used to the rules!  PS:  I do now have a code of my own for this which I can post as a reference design if that is a proper thing to do.

Comment: @Loovjo No, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 236 bytes

```
s=>`
${s}
`.split`
`.map((l,i,a)=>l.replace(/[+-|]/g,(c,j)=>c>`-`?`│`:c>`+`?`─`:`┼┬├╭┤╮??┴?╰?╯`[g(a[i-1][j])+g(l[j-1],1)*2+g(l[j+1],1)*4+g(a[i+1][j])*8]),g=(c,f)=>(f?`+-^v`:`+<>|`).indexOf(c)<0).slice(1,-1).join`
`
```